# Ruby (on Rails) syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I am working back through the "Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial" and trying to understand the syntax at a deeper level. Here is some example code from a helper action that I have defined:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def title
    base_title = "Mega Project"
    if @title.nil?
      base_title
    else
      "#{base_title} | #{@title}"
    end
  end

end
```

My question is about the line: `"#{base_title} | #{@title}"`

What exactly is going on with the structure of this line?

On a higher level, where is the go-to source to look up things like this?

Comment: Thank you for the code edit, Dave. How do I go about this myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within a double quoted string the anything within the #{}s get interpreted as code and the result is embedded in the string so the result you'd expect there is:

"<value of base_title> | <value of title instance variable>".

Comment: Awesome, Nick, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

String interpolation:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation

Answer (score 3):

The most useful way to explore this is with `irb`:

```
1.9.2p290 :001 > base_title = "things"
 => "things" 
1.9.2p290 :002 > title = "stuff"
 => "stuff" 
1.9.2p290 :003 > "#{base_title} | #{title}"
 => "things | stuff"
```

What's actually happening here is that you have a local variable `base_title` that holds a string and an instance variable `@title` that also holds a string. The string with hashes and so on is formatting those variables using string interpolation - a special string syntax that causes the interpreter to plug the variables' values into string when you evaluate it. Here's a [good post](http://kconrails.com/2010/12/08/ruby-string-interpolation/) about it.

I'd recommend getting a book on Ruby.

Comment: Agreed. Poking about with new concepts in Irb (or Pry!) is a valuable tool for every rubyist!

Comment: Thank you, Isaac, this was very helpful. Also, I just checked Amazon and it says that my "Beginning Ruby" book is out for delivery!

Answer (score 2):

`#{}` is variable interpolation within a string. Think of it as a more concise way of saying

```
base_title + " | " + @title
```

In this case it may not be much shorter but when you have long strings with lots of little parts it enhances readability.

A related feature introduced in Ruby 1.9 is interpolation using `%`:

```
"%s | %s" % [base_title, @title]
```

which also allows for formatting (numbers, etc). See [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25).

Answer (score 1):

In ruby `#{}` is used within strings to insert variables. This is called Interpolation.

In this particular piece of code, if a title exists it is added to the base title eg.

```
title: "Super Thingo"
```

becomes

```
"Mega Project | Super Thingo"
```

If no title exists, it just falls back on the base title.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a string with interpolation. Since Ruby methods return the value of the last evaluated expression without an explicit `return`, in the case of `title` being `nil` the string in the `else` branch will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

That line is returning a String with the value of `base_title` and `@title` interpolated as a result of the double quotes.  In this instance, `base_title` is a local variable while `@title` is an instance variable - likely belonging to whatever method in the controller is being called.

For more information check here:
 
[On String Interpolation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation)
[On Scope](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Operators#Scope)