# Meaning of #{ } in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

The operation `#{ }` appears to be so fundamental that my Ruby book completely skips its definition. Can someone provide an explanation?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

#### Why This Is a Good Question

This is a tough question to Google for unless you know the right search terms. The `#{}` operator technically performs **expression substitution** inside a **string literal**.

#### The Answer

The `#{}` literal is the operator used for interpolation inside **double-quoted strings** the same way that the backticks or `$()` construct would be used in Bash. From a practical point of view, the expression inside the literal is evaluated, and then the entire `#{}` expression (including both the operator and the expression it contains) is replaced *in situ* with the result.

#### Related Links

- http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#string
- http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html
- http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation
- [Ruby (on Rails) syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944125/ruby-on-rails-syntax)

Comment: It is worth noting that it also works inside `%Q{...}` strings, heredoc strings, `%W{...}` arrays, backtick commands, `%x{...}` commands and Regexp literals.

Comment: @CodeGnome Yes, it's almost impossible to make Google cough up this information unless you already know the answer.

Answer (score 13):

It allows you to put Ruby code within a string. So:

```
"three plus three is #{3+3}"
```

Would output:

> "three plus three is 6"

It's commonly used to insert variable values into strings without having to mess around with string concatenation:

```
"Your username is #{user}"
```

Answer (score 6):

It's the string interpolation operator, you use it to insert an expression into a string.
Your string needs to be embedded in " to let this magic work, no 's.
It is much faster and better than string concatenation.

```
var = "variable"
"this is a string with a #{var} in" => "this is a string with a variable in"
```