# What is the formal term for the "#{}" token in Ruby syntax?

Tags: ruby, syntax, computer-science

#### The Background

I recently posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10869398/1301972) where I variously referred to `#{}` as a literal, an operator, and (in one draft) a "literal constructor." The squishiness of this definition didn't really affect the quality of the answer, since the question was more about what it does and how to find language references for it, but I'm unhappy with being unable to point to a canonical definition of exactly what to call this element of Ruby syntax.

The [Ruby manual](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#string) mentions this syntax element in the section on [expression substitution](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#exprsub), but doesn't really define the term for the syntax itself. Almost every reference to this language element says it's used *for* string interpolation, but doesn't define what it *is*.

#### Wikipedia Definitions

Here are some Wikipedia definitions that imply this construct is (strictly speaking) neither a literal nor an operator.

1. [Literal (computer programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_%28computer_programming%29)
2. [Operator (programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_%28programming%29)

#### The Questions

Does anyone know what the proper term is for this language element? If so, can you please point me to a formal definition?

Comment: I would call it the string interpolation operator. I don't really think there is a formal definition, though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

Originally, I'd hypothesized:

> *Embedded expression* seems the most likely definition for this token, based on hints in the source code.

This turned out to be true, and has been officially validated by the Ruby 2.x documentation. Based on the updates to the [Ripper documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/ripper/rdoc/Ripper.html) since this answer was originally written, it seems the parser token is formally defined as `string_embexpr` and the symbol itself is called an "embedded expression." See the *Update for Ruby 2.x* section at the bottom of this answer for detailed corroboration.

The remainder of the answer is still relevant, especially for older Rubies such as Ruby 1.9.3, and the methodology used to develop the original answer remains interesting. I am therefore updating the answer, but leaving the bulk of the original post as-is for historical purposes, even though the *current* answer could now be shorter.

### Pre-2.x Answer Based on Ruby 1.9.3 Source Code

#### Related Answer

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10875052/1301972) calls attention to the Ruby source, which makes numerous references to *embexpr* throughout the code base. @Phlip suggests that this variable is an abbreviation for "EMBedded EXPRession." This seems like a reasonable interpretation, but neither the ruby-1.9.3-p194 source nor Google (as of this writing) explicitly references the term *embedded expression* in association with *embexpr* in any context, Ruby-related or not.

#### Additional Research

A scan of the Ruby 1.9.3-p194 source code with:

```
ack-grep -cil --type-add=YACC=.y embexpr .rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194 |
    sort -rnk2 -t: |
    sed 's!^.*/!!'
```

reveals 9 files and 33 lines with the term *embexpr*:

```
test_scanner_events.rb:12
test_parser_events.rb:7
eventids2.c:5
eventids1.c:3
eventids2table.c:2
parse.y:1
parse.c:1
ripper.y:1
ripper.c:1
```

Of particular interest is the inclusion of **string_embexpr** on line 4,176 of the **parse.y** and **ripper.y** bison files. Likewise, **TestRipper::ParserEvents#test_string_embexpr** contains two references to parsing *#{}* on lines 899 and 902 of **test_parser_events.rb**.

The scanner, exercised in **test_scanner_events.rb**, is also noteworthy. This file defines tests in **#test_embexpr_beg** and **#test_embexpr_end** that scan for the token *#{expr}* inside various string expressions. The tests reference both *embexpr* and *expr*, raising the likelihood that "embedded expression" is indeed a sensible name for the thing.

### Update for Ruby 2.x

Since this post was originally written, the documentation for the standard library's Ripper class has been updated to formally identify the token. The [usage section](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/ripper/rdoc/Ripper.html#class-Ripper-label-Usage) provides `"Hello, #{world}!"` as an example, and says in part:

> Within our `:string_literal` you’ll notice two `@tstring_content`, this is the literal part for `Hello,` and `!`. Between the two `@tstring_content` statements is a `:string_embexpr`, where *embexpr* is an embedded expression.

Answer (score 7):

Ruby's parser calls #{} the "**embexpr**" operator. That's EMBedded EXPRession, naturally.

Comment: I found 33 lines containing **embexpr** in the ruby-1.9.3-p194 source, most notably **TestRipper::ParserEvents#test_string_embexpr**. However, I couldn't find any references to **embexpr** being referred to as an *embedded expression* (although that seems likely), nor could I find any references calling it an *operator*. Could you expand your answer a little, and perhaps add a citation or two?

Comment: It's one of the primitives return by the token parser. I worked with that parser before, but those 33 lines are going to have to do it for you. I'd suppose nobody has ever given this question any thought before now!

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely call it neither a literal (that's more for, e.g. *string literals* or *number literals* themselves, but not parts thereof) nor an operator; those are solely for e.g. binary or unary (infix) operators.

I would either just refer to it without a noun (i.e. for string interpolation), or perhaps call those characters the string interpolation sequence or escape.

Comment: Whoever it was that I was chatting with in comments on the now-deleted answer, I'm sorry you felt you had to remove your answer based on our exchange.

Answer (score 0):

This Block post suggests, it is called an 'idiom':
http://kconrails.com/2010/12/08/ruby-string-interpolation/

The Wikipedia Article doesn't seem to contradict that:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_idiom

Comment: It's not *called* an idiom, it *is* an idiom. That's like interpreting "Ruby uses the operator + to add numbers" to mean that "+" is called "operator"

Answer (score -1):

#{} It's called placeholder and is used to reference variables with a string.
puts "My name is #{my_name}"