# what does #{ do in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Meaning of #{ } in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869264/meaning-of-in-ruby)

I know it is used for meta-programming, and I'm having a hard time trying to wrap my mind about what this operator is doing in the following example:

```
class Class
 def attr_accessor_with_history(attr_name)
    attr_name = attr_name.to_s # make sure it's a string
    attr_reader attr_name
    attr_reader attr_name+"_history"
    class_eval %Q"
        def #{attr_name}=(value)
            if !defined? @#{attr_name}_history
                @#{attr_name}_history = [@#{attr_name}]
            end
            @#{attr_name} = value
            @#{attr_name}_history << value
        end
    "
    end
end

class Foo
   attr_accessor_with_history :bar
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general terms, `#{...}` evaluates whatever's inside of it and returns that, converted to a string with `to_s`. This makes it a lot easier to combine several things in a single string.

A typical example:

```
"There are #{n} car#{n == 1 ? '' : 's'} in the #{s}"
```

This is equivalent to:

```
"There are " + n.to_s + " car" + (n == 1 ? '' : 's').to_s + " in the " + s.to+_s
```

It's important to remember that the contents of the `#{...}` interpolation is actually a block of Ruby code and the result of it will be converted to a string before being combined.

That example of meta programming is awfully lazy as `instance_variable_get` and `instance_variable_set` could've been used and `eval` could've been avoided. Most of the time you'll see string interpolation used to create strings, not methods or classes.

There's a more robust formatter with the `String#%` method:

```
"There are %d car%s in the %s" % [ n, (n == 1 ? '' : 's'), s ]
```

This can be used to add a precise number of decimal places, pad strings with spaces, and other useful things.

Answer (score 1):

`#{var}` does variable substitution in Ruby. For example:

`var = "Hello, my name is #{name}"`

The code you've posted is generating a string with the code for an accessor method for the attr_name you've passed in.

Comment: It is called variable interpolation instead of substitution..

Comment: That should be `#{name}` and not `{#name}`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not doing much really :D. All the red text is basically just a string. The "bla #{var} bla" part is just a nicer way of writing "bla " + var + " bla". Try it yourself in irb:

```
a = 10
puts "The Joker stole #{a} pies."
```

Answer (score 0):

what it does is called `variable interpolation`.

```
name = "Bond"
p "The name is #{name}. James #{name}."
```

will output,

```
> "The name is Bond. James Bond."
```